# Browser compatibility for MVC3 Application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jqgrid

I'm using Jqgrid in my pages. It's going to the right side corner of screen when viewed in IE but for Chrome and Mozilla it's fine.

This is my the `<head/>` section of my code. I'm planning on including this in all the pages of my application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="../../Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Please consider that for somebody to help you with your question, they must be able to understand it: what your problem is, and the desired solution. The easier you make it for someone to understand the problem, the more easily they can provide a solution.

Comment: post a small reproduction here

Comment: Ok my problem is i'm facing browser compatabilty issue in my MVC3 application where i have used JQgrid and css bootstrap styles for buttons and design. When i run the application its coming perfect in Mozila, but for chrome its little bit coming and in IE the grid itself going to the right side of window please i'm not getting any idea why its happening. Sorry for my english if anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Browsers may have different JavaScript engine, render Html and css differently, but ASP has nothing to do with browser.